# How can I dynamically display data base on ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to dynamic display data depending on the ID from the app.js. I'm sending the ID correctly but the other page ins't receiving the ID

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';
import Top from './top.js';
import Bottom from './bottom';
import Right from './right';
import Left from './left';
import Center from './center';
import About from './about';
import Help from './help';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter  as Router , Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
          <Container fluid className="p-0 min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
              <Row fluid className = "flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 shadow-sm" > 
                <bs.Col className = "px-3 py-2">
                  <Top/>

                </bs.Col>
              </Row>

              <Row noGutters className = "flex-grow-1">
                <Col md="2" className ="px-3 py-4 shadow" style ={{backgroundColor: "#99CCCC"}}>
                  <Left/>
                </Col>

                <Col md="8">
                  <Switch>

                      <Route path ="/">
                        <Center />
                      </Route>
                <Route path = "/product-detail/:{props.product.id}" >
                        <ProductsDetail/>
                  </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Col>

                <Col md = "2" className = "px-3 py-4 shadow" style ={{backgroundColor: "#343a40"}}>
                  <Right/>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row fluid>
                <Col className = "d-flex justify-content-center px-3 py-2" style ={{backgroundColor: "#28a745"}}><Bottom/></Col>
              </Row> 
          </Container>
      </Router>
  )

}

export default App;
```

It sends the ID but now on the other page doesn't display the data that I want to use

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useParams} from "react-router";

function ProductsDetail(props) {
    let {id}= useParams()
  return (
    <div>
        <p>
            Description: {id}
            </p>
    </div>
  )

}

export default ProductsDetail;
```

I have been trying using useParams() but I don't correctly understand how am I suppose to grab the ID and display the information. Also, I have been using props to send the ID.

Comment: Those two code blocks are identical

Comment: I don't see you import ProductsDetail in you App

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the `id` to the component, you don't need to have from `useParams` if you pass it directly like this

App:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';
import Top from './top.js';
import Bottom from './bottom';
import Right from './right';
import Left from './left';
import Center from './center';
import About from './about';
import Help from './help';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter  as Router , Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
          <Container fluid className="p-0 min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
              <Row fluid className = "flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 shadow-sm" > 
                <bs.Col className = "px-3 py-2">
                  <Top/>

                </bs.Col>
              </Row>

              <Row noGutters className = "flex-grow-1">
                <Col md="2" className ="px-3 py-4 shadow" style ={{backgroundColor: "#99CCCC"}}>
                  <Left/>
                </Col>

                <Col md="8">
                  <Switch>

                      <Route path = {"/product-detail/${props.product.id}"} >
                        <Center />
                      </Route>
                <Route path = "/product-detail/:{props.product.id}" >
                        <ProductsDetail id={props.product.id}/>
                  </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Col>

                <Col md = "2" className = "px-3 py-4 shadow" style ={{backgroundColor: "#343a40"}}>
                  <Right/>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row fluid>
                <Col className = "d-flex justify-content-center px-3 py-2" style ={{backgroundColor: "#28a745"}}><Bottom/></Col>
              </Row> 
          </Container>
      </Router>
  )

}

export default App;
```

ProductsDetail:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useParams} from "react-router";

function ProductsDetail(props) {
    let {id}= useParams()
  return (
    <div>
        <p>
            Description: {props.id}
            </p>
    </div>
  )

}

export default ProductsDetail;
```